# Angular JS initiation and display in MVC5

Tags: angularjs

So here is my MVC5 project view cshtml file, can anyone tell me why my model "Check" doesnt show and get initialed at all

```
 <div ng-cotroller="HouseInArea_Module_Control" class="container">
 <div ng-init="getHouseInArea()">
 <label>start</label><input type="text" ng-model="HouseBasket"> {{HouseBasket}} {{Check}}
 </div>
 </div>

  <script>   
   function HouseInArea_Module_Control($scope) {
    $scope.HouseBasket = 0;
    $scope.Check = 2;
    $scope.getHouseInArea = function () {
        $scope.Check = 1;
    };
   }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing AngualarJS properly and there is a typo it should be `ng-controller` not `ng-cotroller`.  Also, I don't *think* you can use ng-init with a function, I believe it's only for use with a data structure (and it's generally not considered a good practice).

Given all the errors, It would probably help you to go through the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), but here's the syntax to use

```
angular
 .module('myApp', [])
 .controller('HouseInArea_Module_Control', function($scope) {
    $scope.HouseBasket = 0;
    $scope.Check = 2;
    $scope.getHouseInArea = function () {
      $scope.Check = 1;
    };

    $scope.getHouseInArea(); // call the initialization function when the controller loads instead of using ng-init
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Someone taught me use this way to implement. Also the ng-init works too

Answer (score 0):

You can move the call to getHouseInArea into the controller itself assuming you want it to run every time the controller is invoked. Note the inclusion of ng-app and the ng-controller typo correction that Jason mentioned.

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/hXrtDUTGXQrMkf6iYOK4/preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      function HouseInArea_Module_Control($scope) {
        $scope.HouseBasket = 0;
        $scope.Check = 2;
        $scope.getHouseInArea = function () {
          $scope.Check = 1;
        };
        // main
        $scope.getHouseInArea(); 
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="HouseInArea_Module_Control" class="container">
      <div>
        <label>start</label><input type="text" ng-model="HouseBasket">
        {{HouseBasket}} {{Check}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```